# 2 column Flexbox equal heights but different column widths

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create two columns, A and B.

Div A has a width of 25% and div B has a width of 70%.

I want div A to match the height of div B, which is working.

However, the columns widths appear to be the same?

How can I get equal heights with different column widths working together?

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/a89xoqmp/

```
.wrap {
    display: flex;
/*   flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap; */
}

.banner-message {
  flex: 1;
  border: 4px solid black;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;

    &.one {
      width: 25%;
    }

    &.two {
      width: 70%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `flex: 1` from `.banner-message`.

This shorthand rule breaks down to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`.

The `flex-grow: 1` component, which is applied *after* the `width` / `flex-basis` is computed, causes the items to consume free space equally.

Answer (score 1):

As @Michael_B answered, you'd want to remove `flex: 1` from `.banner-message`.  To elaborate on his answer, the `flex` property is a shorthand property for: `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`

**CSS Syntax:**

```
flex: [flex-grow] [flex-shrink] [flex-basis|auto|initial|inherit];
```

So by specifying `flex: 1` you are essentially setting `flex-grow: 1` on all `.banner-message` elements. If all elements are set to grow, they will take up equal space.